# Nested form attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have one form working to save in the database but I want to save some fields that are going to be saved in a different record.

```
<%= form_for @complaint, url: {action: 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :complaint_info %>
  <%= f.fields_for :witness do |witnesses_form| %>
    <%= witnesses_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
  def new
    @complaint = Complaint.new
  end

  def create
    @complaint = current_user.complaints.build(complaint_params)
    if @complaint.save

      redirect_to dashboard_complaint_path(@complaint)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def complaint_params
    params.require(:complaint).permit(:complaint_info, witnesses_attributes: [:name])
  end
```

on the model:

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :witnesses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :witnesses
end
```

.

```
class Witness < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :complaint
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Unpermitted parameter: witness`

Everything seems to be as it suppose to be, what am I missing here?

EDIT:

was able to save the record by adding:

`@complaint.witnesses.build`

to the `create` action in the controller but it is still not letting me save the `:name` there

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Witness id: 1, name: nil, phone: nil, complaint_id: 8, created_at: "2015-06-08 20:05:06", updated_at: "2015-06-08
```

EDIT 2:

Was able to fix it by moving the `@complaint.witnesses.build` from the `create` action to the `new` action and it fixed it, now I can create the record and lets me save the text_fields in it.

Comment: @chad_ what do you mean?

Comment: Does `fields_for @company.witnesses` work better?

Comment: @chad_ you mean `@complaint.witnesses`, tried it, it renders the field with already `Witness` typed in, tried it and it gave me the same result, didn't saved the `name:`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with changing your controller and views codes as following

In controller

```
 def new
   @complaint = Complaint.new
   @witnesses = @complaint.witnesses.build
 end

 def edit
   @witnesses = @complaint.witnesses
 end
```

In views

```
  <%= f.fields_for :witnesses, @witnesses do |witnesses_form| %>
     <%= witnesses_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: `@complaint.witnesses.build` returns a single new entry .-.

Comment: Was able to fix it by adding `@complaint.witnesses.build` to the `new` action instead of the `create` one.

Comment: @Johhan  if this work for you, you can accept the answer and this will help people to find solutions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding `@complaint.witnesses.build` to the `new`action instead of the `create` action.

So my controller now looks like this:

```
  def new
    @complaint = Complaint.new
    @complaint.witnesses.build
  end

  def create
    @complaint = current_user.complaints.build(complaint_params)
    if @complaint.save

      redirect_to dashboard_complaint_path(@complaint)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def complaint_params
    params.require(:complaint).permit(:complaint_info, witnesses_attributes: [:name])
  end
```